# preg_match just returns 'Array'?

Tags: php

when using this code to fetch data from http://www.ea.com/uk/football/profile/Calfreezy/360 the code just echo's back the word 'Array'

Here is the code I'm using currently:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("http://www.ea.com/uk/football/profile/Calfreezy/360");

preg_match('#<div class="stat">Titles Won<span>([0-9\.]*)<span class="sprite13 goalImage cup"></span></span>#', $content, $titleswon);

echo 'Titles Won: '.$titleswon.'';

?>
```

And this is the HTML I am trying to pull from the url:

```
<div class="stat">
                Titles Won                <span>0<span class="sprite13 goalImage cup"></span></span>
            </div>
```

This is just returning  Titles won: Array

When if working it should return Titles won: 0

What am I doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: Because it's an array, not a string. Use `var_dump($titleswon)` to see the contents and choose which bit you want (use 'view source' to see it formatted nicely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns an array as can be seen from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

if you want to see all the contents of the array use

```
var_dump( $titleswon );
```

If you just need the matched, you have to address that specific part.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the entire matches array instead of selecting the index(es) that you want from it and printing them.

See [the documentation](http://php.net/preg_match)

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

preg_match() produces an array of matches. If you print out an array in string context, you get `Array` as the text. e.g.

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar');

echo $arr; // prints "Array"
echo $arr['foo']; // prints "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be :

```
if (preg_match('#<div class="stat">Titles Won<span>([0-9\.]*)<span class="sprite13 goalImage cup"></span></span>#', $content, $titleswon)) {
   echo 'Titles Won: '.$titleswon[1].'';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The third param tho preg_match is passed by reference and will contain an array with matches in every capture group. You are using two "groups". The whole match and `([0-9\.]*)` which will be the second. So I expect you need this:

```
echo 'Titles Won: '.$titleswon[1].''; // note the array is indexed by 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look to the preg_match documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

You can see that in the $match argument is actually an array, $match[0] containing the whole match, and the consecutive array elements containing the subqueries.

If you do `var_dump($titleswon)` or `print_r($titleswon)` you will see the whole information, then you can access to the desired info, in your case it would be `$titleswon[1]`